# Extract certain files from iso with fastest speed

Tags: macos, high-sierra, iso, hdiutil

I have several blu-ray iso downloaded from the internet, and it seems like the iso is compressed, so the reading speed is limited to about 10 MB/s max (the drive containing it is about 125MB/s max), and I can't even play the files directly. Using keka, 7z, and rar all failed. I only need the m2ts files, so is there a way to extract certain files from a iso at an acceptable speed?

System: macOS High Sierra, mbp 2017

Errors:

```
7zr l -tudf /volumes/Seagate\ 5T\ \(Joy\ Jin\)/DSM\ tmp/STUDIO\ GHIBLI\ Hayao\ Miyazaki\ Collection\ 1979-2013\ BluRay\ 1080p\ AVC\ DTS-HD\ MA6.1\ DTS-HD\ MA2.0\ LPCM2.0-jamesyao@CHDBits/\[00\]\ Lupin\ III\ The\ Castle\ of\ Cagliostro\ 1979\ BluRay\ 1080p\ AVC\ LPCM2.0-jamesyao@CHDBits.iso

7-Zip (a) [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=zh_CN.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)



ERROR:
Unsupported archive type
```

Same thing with 7za. I can't use 7z because of the following error that I tried troubleshooting but failed:

```
7z l -tudf /volumes/Seagate\ 5T\ \(Joy\ Jin\)/DSM\ tmp/STUDIO\ GHIBLI\ Hayao\ Miyazaki\ Collection\ 1979-2013\ BluRay\ 1080p\ AVC\ DTS-HD\ MA6.1\ DTS-HD\ MA2.0\ LPCM2.0-jamesyao@CHDBits/\[00\]\ Lupin\ III\ The\ Castle\ of\ Cagliostro\ 1979\ BluRay\ 1080p\ AVC\ LPCM2.0-jamesyao@CHDBits.iso

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=zh_CN.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs x64)

Can't load '/usr/local/lib/p7zip/7z.dll' ()
Can't load '/usr/local/lib/p7zip/Codecs/Rar.so' ()


ERROR:
7-Zip cannot find the code that works with archives.
```

rar:

```
unrar l /volumes/Seagate\ 5T\ \(Joy\ Jin\)/tmp.iso 

UNRAR 5.71 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2019 Alexander Roshal

/volumes/Seagate 5T (Joy Jin)/tmp.iso is not RAR archive
```

unarchiver:
[image]

Comment: None of the tools you use allow you to play videos or access the content of an ISO file, so it‘s not really clear what you are trying to accomplish? Why don‘t you mount the image and just copy the relevant files?

Comment: @nohillside Because it's way too slow. It would be great if I can just mount the image and play files in there, but the speed is too slow to allow real-time streaming. I think perhaps a utility focused on only extraction might perform better than mounting and then copying.

Comment: 7z and unrar are used to extract archives, they can't extract files from an ISO or a DMG.